# how to get status of downloads using HCDownload

Tags: ios, objective-c, download-manager, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using the code below to download multiple files and the files are getting downloaded properly.

```
HCDownloadViewController *dlvc = [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init];
dlvc.downloadDirectory = @"/var/mobile/Library/Downloads";
dlvc.delegate = self;
[dlvc downloadURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url1"] userInfo:nil];
[dlvc downloadURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url2"] userInfo:nil];
[dlvc downloadURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url3"] userInfo:nil];
```

Now what I wanted to do is go to another view controller where I will show a list of current downloads that are going on, however I am unable to understand how can I do it.

Has anyone had an issue like this before, or knows the solution to fix this?